# Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError in PostsController#update with Paperclip and AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I've been working on this for hours and haven't been able to figure it out. I ran git clean and then realized that my s3.yml file got deleted. I created new keys and put them in a new s3.yml file. I haven't changed anything else from before which was working just fine. What am I missing?

I'm getting: `Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError (unable to sign request without credentials set):`

Here is my code:

development.rb

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_region: 'us-east-1',
    bucket:'mybucket',
    s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"
  }
```

production.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
      storage: :s3,
      s3_credentials: {
        bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
        access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
      }
    }
    # Secret key base for non-existent secrets.yml file
    config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

s3.yml (with new access keys)

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME: mybucket
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
AWS_REGION: us-east-1
```

Post class

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :category

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true

  has_attached_file :thumbnail, styles: {
      medium: '270x170#',
      large: '560x280#',
      large2: '540x340#'
    }

    # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
    validates_attachment_content_type :thumbnail, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Comment: Which environment is giving you that error? dev or prod?

Comment: @TheOni development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting the error on dev environment I think that the error is due to **s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"**.

Given the s3.yml you have posted I don't think that **s3_credentials** will be filled with a json structure like the one you have in production environment.

I suggest you to load the file and fill the json like you do in your production environment.

Comment: I think that was the problem, but when I changed it to what I have in production, I got `fetch': key not found: “S3_BUCKET_NAME”.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction! :)) I needed to add values to the ENV variables in the terminal by doing: export ENV_VARIABLE_NAME="value"